# How to display <img> tag using javascript as the active text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to display the icons for `<li>` tags instead of the text when it's selected. Please take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Zenko/PUAY7/4/

**Update:** Solution fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/Zenko/PUAY7/12/

**HTML**

```
<section class="main">
<div class="wrapper-demo">
    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
        <span>Transport</span>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/finalflags/16/United-States-Flag.png" />classic mail</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">UPS Delivery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Private jet</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
    this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li > a');
    this.val = '';
    this.index = -1;
    this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
        var obj = this;

        obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            return false;
        });

        obj.opts.on('click',function(){
            var opt = $(this);
            obj.val = opt.text();
            obj.index = opt.index();
            obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
        });
    },
    getValue : function() {
        return this.val;
    },
    getIndex : function() {
        return this.index;
    }
}

$(function() {

    var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

    $(document).click(function() {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

If you look at my jsfiddle you can see the flag icon is not being displayed when item is selected. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: css file is missing.( bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css)

Comment: @hari I posted an outdated version, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zenko/PUAY7/12/ it's now working perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change This js code like.

```
obj.opts.on('click',function(){
     var opt = $(this);
     obj.val = opt.html();
     obj.index = opt.index();
     obj.placeholder.html(obj.val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add this css link

```
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PUAY7/10/)